# Count rows in a block of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to count rows in a range of cells, C2:D10. I use above code to select them, but I have no idea, how to count rows in this interval.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C2:D10").Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to get the number of rows, columns, etc. in a range which is a **block**:

```
Set r = Range("C2:D10")

nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
MsgBox ("last row " & nLastRow)

nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
MsgBox ("last column " & nLastColumn)

nFirstRow = r.Row
MsgBox ("first row " & nFirstRow)

nFirstColumn = r.Column
MsgBox ("first column " & nFirstColumn)

numrow = r.Rows.Count
MsgBox ("number of rows " & numrow)

numcol = r.Columns.Count
MsgBox ("number of columns " & numcol)
```

Answer (score 2):

ActiveSheet.Range("C2:D10").Rows.Count